# Trying to get started with Zend Framework 1.12.7

Tags: php, zend-framework

Hi guys I am having a lot of trouble getting started with `Zend Framework 1.12`. Basically I've managed to get my project set up in `Netbeans` and I have it located on my `localhost`. When I go to this `URL` I get the default page:

```
http://localhost/zendtest2/application/views/scripts/index/index.phtml
```

But when I go to this page I get a list of my file tree in the localhost directory

```
http://localhost/zendtest2/
```

I guess what I am trying to understand is how to I get the `http://localhost/zendtest2/` to point to the `http://localhost/zendtest2/application/views/scripts/index/index.phtml` or is that how I would even do it?

I know there is a `public` folder in my project with an `index.php` file. Is there some way that I should be reaching that page when the project initially starts?

Comment: You always need to use index.php in your public folder. Set Virtual Hosts - http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.create-project.html#learning.quickstart.create-project.vhost

Answer (score 2):

To me this sounds more like an environment issue rather than a zend framework issue. I am not entirely sure what your dev environment is, but I am going to assume you're using apache as your HTTP server:

https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings

Again, I am not entirely sure what OS you're using so you'll need to find your httpd.conf file yourself.

You then have two options, adding the redirect/route there (that may be wrong) or (more recommended) uncommenting the httpd-vhosts.conf link:

```
# Virtual hosts
#Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Then including the new route in there. Heres a basic example (again you'll need to add what you need):

```
<VirtualHost *:8888>
    ServerName zf2-tutorial.localhost
    DocumentRoot "/Users/stevenc/****DIR_STUFF****/skeleton-application/public"
</VirtualHost>
```

Anything beyond that can be set as your home route in the module.config.php of the Application module within your zend project:

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'home' => array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'BookList\Controller\Book',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

Also, if you're not using ZF 1.12 for any particular reason, ZF2.3* is the latest.